# .NET DeflateStream Usage

Tags: .net, inflate, deflate, deflatestream

I am trying to utilize the INFLATE compression stream in .NET using a `DeflateStream`.  My code throws an `InvalidDataException` although I know that the data I am passing has been correctly processed by the DEFLATE algorithm (it has been tested).  Am I using the `DeflateStream` incorrectly?  My code is as follows:

```
public byte[] Inflate(byte[] deflateArr)
    {
        MemoryStream ms;

        // try to create a MemoryStream from a byte array
        try
        {
            ms = new MemoryStream(deflateArr);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // create a deflatestream and pass it the memory stream
        DeflateStream ds;
        try
        {
            ds = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // create a bytes array and read into it
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

        try
        {
            ds.Read(bytes, 0, 4096);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (InvalidDataException)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // close the memory stream
        ms.Close();

        // close the deflate stream
        ds.Close();

        return bytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're not.

Things wrong with this code:

- Explicitly calling `Close()` instead of using a `using` statement. Probably not harmful here, but a bad idea.
- Catching various exceptions which you *really* shouldn't be catching at all, as they indicate programming bugs
- Catching exceptions on a per-statement basis, even though you're treating them the same way throughout the code (so could catch the exceptions for a much larger block)
- Ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read`

Here's a better version, assuming you're using .NET 4 (for `Stream.CopyTo`)

```
public static byte[] Inflate(byte[] inputData)
{
    using (Stream input = new DeflateStream(new MemoryStream(inputData),
                                            CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
            return output.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you *may* want to catch `InvalidDataException` - personally I wouldn't at this point, but it *may* make sense to do so. (I'd catch it at the calling side, if necessary. You can always wrap this method in another one if necessary.)

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what is the downside of catching exceptions?

Comment: @cytinus: It's hiding a bug. If your method returns null, you have *no idea why* and your program will keep running - whereas if the exception bubbles up, you can tell that you've got an error, and you don't try to keep going with bad data. Something like `ArgumentNullException` should always be due to a bug somewhere - so you want to find that bug ASAP.

Comment: Oh, my actual code contains a bunch of logging, and if that method returns null the calling method kills the program with an error message.  Everything is logged to the Windows Event logger, I just deleted that code from the question because it wasn't pertinent to my question.

Comment: Also by `DefaultStream` do you mean `DeflateStream`?

Comment: @cytinus: Yes, `DefaultStream` was a typo. But adding all those catch blocks is still a really bad idea. Let the exception bubble up to the top of the stack *then* log it in a central location and kill the program if necessary.

Comment: Oh I get it now.  Thanks a lot.  Also your code works, so I must have been doing something wrong.